# Could not set default culture in BlazorServer

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

Hello everyone I am working on the project that I need to use multiple language and then I want to set default culture. Everything is working fine but I couldn't set default culture.
Project is starting with default English language, even though I changed it to Russian language as I showed code below. Please help me thank you.

=====================================================
Program.cs file

```
using AnalysisDashboard.Authentication;
using AnalysisDashboard.Data;   
using AnalysisDashboard.DataAccess;
using AnalysisDashboard.Models;
using AnalysisDashboard.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Globalization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DashboardContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseMySQL(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthenticationCore();
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ProtectedSessionStorage>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, 
CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<UserAccountService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRegistrationService, RegistrationService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<DataInfo>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
  app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "uz-UZ", "uz-Cyrl", "ru-RU" };
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
.SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[3])
.AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
.AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);

app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions); 

app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

=====================================================
Index.razor.cs file

```
public void ClickLanguage(string lanCode)
    {
        string selectedCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
        switch (lanCode)
        {
            case "uz":      selectedCulture = "uz-UZ";   break;
            case "uzCyrl":  selectedCulture = "uz-Cyrl"; break;
            case "ru":      selectedCulture = "ru-RU";   break;
            case "en":      selectedCulture = "en-US";   break;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedCulture))
        {
            return;
        }

        var uri = new Uri(Navigation.Uri).GetComponents(UriComponents.PathAndQuery, UriFormat.Unescaped);
        var query = $"?culture={Uri.EscapeDataString(selectedCulture)}&" + $"redirectUri={Uri.EscapeDataString(uri)}";

        Navigation.NavigateTo("/Culture/SetCulture" + query, forceLoad: true); 
    }
```

=====================================================
CultureController.cs file

```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

  namespace AnalysisDashboard.Controllers
  {
      [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
      public class CultureController : Controller
      {
           public IActionResult SetCulture(string culture, string redirectUri)
           {
              if (culture != null)
              {
                  HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
                         CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                         CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(
                         new RequestCulture(culture)));
              }

               return LocalRedirect(redirectUri);
           }
      }
   }
```